# Bounded solution of partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> A bounded solution to the partial differential equation $\frac{\partial u} {\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 u} {\partial^2 x} + e^{-t}$.
>   A. $u(x,t) = e^{-t}$
>   B. $u(x,t) = e^{-x} e^{-t}$
>   C. $u(x,t) = e^{-x} + e^{-t}$
>   D. $u(x,t) = x- e^{-t}$

My Approach:
I found option (d) to be correct by hit and trial of the options mentioned above. Now, my question is how to find the solution with some standard method.

Comment: I am afraid (d) is unbounded because $x$ is unbounded on $\mathbb{R}$, unless you claim a bounded domain for $x$...

Comment: Can you please help me out to get the solution of this problem with some standard method. @hypernova

Comment: There seems not enough information, i.e., in what domain is $x$ defined. If it is bounded intervals like $x\in\left[a,b\right]$, [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Solving_the_heat_equation_using_Fourier_series) would do. If it is $\mathbb{R}$ but $u$ is supposed to be integrable, [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Fundamental_solutions) would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much @hypernova

Comment: My pleasure :-)